# Python - Функция проверки и сравнения содержимого в 2х папках

Tags: python-3.x

Я новичок в Python. Пишу свой Pet проект. Мне нужна функция которая будет открывать 2 папки и производить сравнения содержимого в названиях файлов (если название содержит - то).
Я понимаю как должна работать логика, но как это реализовать не знаю. Каша уже в голове.

Нужно сравнить имена файлов в 1 папке с именами файлов во 2 папке.

Если есть совпадения имен во 2 папке с первой, то из 2й все совпадающие файлы перенести в 3 папку.

Имена могут совпадать не полностью.

Например:

В 1 парке лежит файл с именем — approaching-1-none-2b2e.txt

Во второй папке файл лежит файл — bubbles-moak-2b2e.txt

Если в названиях файлов в 1 папке присутствует - 2b2e, то файл с 2й папке с имененм включающим в себя 2b2e, перенести в 3 папку. Мне нужно сравнить совпадения в названиях файлов лежащих во 2 папке с 1й. Если такие есть, перенести их в 3ю. Я не знаю как еще объяснить )))

Comment: видно, что каша :D ничего не понятно, что нужно сделать и какая логика. В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Нужно сравнить имена файлов в 1 папке с именами файлов во 2 папке. Если есть совпадения имен во 2 папке с первой, то из 2 все совпадающие файлы перенести в 3 папку. Имена могут совпадать не полностью.
Например: 
В 1 парке лежит файл с именем — approaching-1-none-2b2e.txt
Во второй папке файл лежит файл — bubbles-moak-2b2e.txt 
Если в названиях файлов в 1 и 2 папки присутствует -  2b2e, то этот файл со второй папки перенести в 3 папку. Мне нужно сравнить совпадения в названиях файлов лежащих во 2 папке с 1й. Если такие есть, перенести их в 3ю. Я не знаю как еще объяснить )))

Comment: а что считать совпадением? Если в именах присутствует буква "a" это уже совпадение или еще нет?

Comment: Думаю точное совподение  подряд стоящих смимволов от 3 до 15 символов

Comment: Я пока не понимаю как это реализовать даже в голове

Comment: ChatGPT пытались спросить? он наверное все не решит. Но явно подскажет как и что делать и даст наработки кода.

Comment: Мне бы хотя бы что-то примерное, от чего я смогу оттолкнуться. Пусть не в яблочко, просто как идея. Я не понимаю даже приблизительно как это осуществить. Наш мозг как то же это делает — он берет шаблоны и находит в них паттерные совпадения — от туда и дежавю.